# How can I access veryfit app database on my device?

Tags: applications, sqlite

I have installed VeryFit2.0 app on my mobile.I want to see previous days heart beat data but there is no option.Is there are way by which I can get in to the database of the app as I know its an offline app ?

Comment: In my version, the database is located at `/storage/emulated/0/veryfit2/log/db_veryfit2.db` and I have been able to copy it to my computer and examine it with `sqlite3`. But the HEART_RATE table has only 4 data points in it! Even though current heart rate does display on the main tab.

Answer (score 5):

Responding about the database location:  The database on the sd card looks like a backup of sorts.  The real database is found in the system : `System/data/data/com.veryfit/multi` 
I found it using android studio.  However if your phone is not rooted you can't access the directory.  But if you use adb you can create a backup of that folder on your computer: `adb backup -noapk com.veryfit.multi` 
Once you have the backup.ab you need to unpack it.  I used Android Backup Extractor .  That will give you a .tar file that you can open and explore the database using sqlite3  
Links where I found this info: 
**access data inside data/data/**  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006315/how-to-access-data-data-folder-in-android-device

**extracting an ab file**  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533567/how-to-extract-or-unpack-an-ab-file-android-backup-file

Answer (score 1):

From the Reference Guide PDF:  You can also select to see a previous day’s activity by selecting the “Down” arrow below “Today”. This will allow you to then select a previous day to review those stats. To close this option, just select anywhere on the screen for that information to go away

Another option would be to use the "Share" icon in the upper left to send the data to an external source for later review.

http://www.ktipromo.com/Fitness_Activity_Tracker_Reference_Guide.pdf

Comment: It only tells steps count for previous days not heart rate

Comment: Also if you use the "Details" button at the bottom of the app it allows you to scroll back thru several weeks and view all the data points along a graph.

Comment: @TryThis - the Detail tab only offers "Activities" (steps) and "Sleep" views. Where are you seeing the heart rate info?